# How do I find center of drawable for android canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-drawable

I have a drawable resource that I need to draw on a canvas. I need to have the drawable centered at point `(x,y)`. Right now if I do `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, mPaint)`, `(x,y)` represent `(left,top)`. Does anyone know how I may get the center of my drawable so I can place it on the canvas correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the width and height of the canvas.
Now, you need to draw it on width/2 and height/2.

To be more centered, you can subtract from width/2 half of the bitmap width, and from height/2 half of the bitmap height.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, width/2-mBitmap.getWidth()/2, height/2-mBitmap.getHeight()/2, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 3):

A Simple math...

```
    int centerX = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
```